# Spacy on AppEngine standard

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, spacy

I'm trying to use Spacy on the new AppEngine Standard Python 3.7 runtime.

When I try to deploy I get:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cannot upload file
>   [/my/project/path/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/lang/tr/lemmatizer.py],
>   which has size [41523943] (greater than maximum allowed size of
>   [33554432]). Please delete the file or add to the skip_files entry in
>   your application .yaml file and try again.

A few oddities:

- The docs seem to indicate that I don't need to upload the virtual environment and it will be created from requirements.txt
- Looking at the log file, it seems to ignore .pyc files, but not the venv directory
- The error message says to `add to the skip_files in your application .yaml file and try again.`, but the docs say the python3.7 runtime doesn't use skip files and to use a [.gcloudignore file](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) instead, but adding `venv/` or `venv/*` doesn't work (it appears to be ignored)

Comment: Did you use `gcloud app deploy` or `gcloud beta app deploy`? According to the doc you referenced just the beta version supports the `.gcloudignore` file presently. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks. After I wrote this I thought about it and realized I hadn't updated gcloud in a while. I did a gcloud update then had to reauth and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I needed up update gcloud and reauthenticate:

```
gcloud components update
gcloud auth login
```