# Unable to deploy after adding torch dependency on GCP App Engine Flex

Tags: numpy, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, torch, google-cloud-build

I was adding `torch` to our python project using:

```
poetry add torch
```

With this it added the following in my pyproject.toml
`torch = "^2.0.0"`

After this, when deploying I noticed that the GCP Cloud build times went upwards of 40minutes+ (which I could mitigate by increasing the timeout to 40minutes+ .. yeah bad hack)

When I tried to deploy it, it kept throwing me the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2023-04-06T18:18:10.984Z2529.ue.0:
No sufficient free disk space left for your App Engine Flexible application.
Please increase your VM instances disk size in the resource settings in the
app.yaml file for your deployment and retry.
See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings
for how to set disk resource.
```

I increased the resources on my system to:

```
resources:
  cpu: 3
  memory_gb: 15 #cpu * [1.0 - 6.5] - 0.4 , we are using 3 for the range value
  disk_size_gb: 40
```

At this point, I used `numpy` for the computation and it did the job for now.. but I would love to have the option to deploy to GCP, thanks for the help!

Comment: The error message told you the solution: `Please increase your VM instances disk size`

Comment: I would think that 40GB is enough disk size for the instance, but maybe not?

Comment: What was the size previously that reported the error? You do not want an instance to run low on disk space. That is suicide for performance and reliability.

Comment: It was 40GB (same as the code sample I posted on the thread) I don't really know why it was failing to deploy with 40GB of space. I was tempted to up it even more, but I am probably missing something

Comment: I deploy torch 1.13 with 20GB disk.  I wouldn't expect torch 2 to require too much more.  See here for a possible cause and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228492

Comment: Double-check which files and directories you are deploying.

Comment: so turns out its an issue with [poetry](https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/12twoc0/unable_to_deploy_after_adding_torch_dependency_on/) TLDR: poetry pulling in all pytorch versions 